# How can I fetch JSON files from a folder, in a React + React-Router app?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-router

I`m developing a web app entirely written in React.js. It built on [this](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) boilerplate, and will be deployed on an apache server.

The app uses jQuery AJAX to make GET & POST requests to remote APIs (results are in JSONP format). Now I need to fetch JSON files stored on a "real" folder (not a react-router path) called "./json". How can I do this?

Comment: As long as you're requesting a file that's the same origin as the web page (i.e. the page is being served from `https://foo.bar` and you are requesting `https://foo.bar/json/baz.json`) you can generally get it with AJAX as long as the server is configured to serve those files. For example if you're using node.js you need to make sure that you're actually serving `https://foo.bar/json/baz.json` over HTTP. Edit: oh you're using Apache -- well, same story, make sure Apache is serving your JSON files over HTTP.

Comment: I`m not using httpS. jQuery ajaxing a JSON file (no matter where is located) always returns the index.html code.

Comment: Like I said above, you need to configure your server to actually serve the JSON file over HTTP. Since you're using React your server is probably configured to redirect all requests to `index.html` in the fashion of most React single page apps. In fact looking at the boilerplate you're using, Node is doing just that. Loading JSON with AJAX is something that obviously works in most circumstances, and if it's not, it has to be a server configuration issue. https://jsfiddle.net/_jered/e5zjqj0b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boilerplate you are using works with Node.js and express. If you want it to serve static assets (i.e. files) over a route then you need to configure it to do so.

Since your JSON files are in their own folder, it would probably look something like this:

```
app.use(express.static('json'));
```

Comment: That helped me to achieve my goal

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting your app from the Facebook's 'create-react-app' instructions found here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html

Then I found an easy way to be able to access JSON files from the URL without having the React Router get in the way and intercept the request.

All you have to do is in your index.js of that 'create-react-app' scaffolding, add something like this as the very first line:
`import './myJsonFile.json';`

And that's it, as afterwards going to: http://localhost:3000/myJsonFile.json would correctly fetch the file without React router interfering in the lookup.